# Unzip files from another ftp

Tags: php, ftp, unzip

I would like to extract files in a second ftp account?

I tried this script, but it does not work:

```
$zip = new ZipArchive;
$zip->open('ftp://user:password@host/tmp/file.zip'); 
$zip->extractTo('ftp://user:password@host/public_html/'); 
$zip->close();
```

In an attempt to debug, I added the following:

```
$zip = new ZipArchive;
$res = $zip->open('ftp://user:password@host/tmp/file.zip');
if ($res === TRUE) {
    echo 'ok';
    $zip->extractTo('ftp://user:password@host/public_html/');
    $zip->close();
} else {
    echo 'failed, code:' . $res;
}
```

From this I discovered that the `$zip->open` command is failing, with error code `11`.

I don't know what to do for further debugging. Does anyone have any suggestions about what might be wrong?

Comment: Why do you think it is not working? Does the same thing work if you were using your local ftp account? Do you have write permissions in the place where you want to write?

Comment: @Floris I don't know why this not work and yes i have write permissions in the place (public_html). This script returns no error but still not extract.

Comment: @Floris Problem is in zip open()

Comment: Can you confirm you have r/w permission on the file in the original location? There are some flags you can pass in - and on some systems they are apparently not optional. See the comments in - e.g. http://us3.php.net/manual/en/ziparchive.open.php#88765 _Even though the api specifies that the flags are optional I found that I had to specify the flag ZIPARCHIVE::CREATE for an archive to be opened._ 
This is on a Windows 7 system with PHP 5.3.0

Comment: @Floris Yes i can confirm. I have add ZIPARCHIVE::CREATE but still not work.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using [`ftp_get()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ftp-get.php) to grab the file locally before operating on it.

```
$conn_id = ftp_connect( 'host' );
$login_result = ftp_login($conn_id, 'user', 'password');
if (ftp_get($conn_id, 'file.zip', 'tmp/file.zip', FTP_BINARY)) {
    // Success! File is now at local "file.zip"

    $zip = new ZipArchive;
    $zip->open( 'file.zip' ); 
    $zip->extractTo('ftp://user:password@host/public_html/'); 
    $zip->close();

} else {
    echo "There was a problem\n";
}

ftp_close($conn_id);
```

Comment: I tried and get this error: PHP Warning:  ZipArchive::close() [<a href='ziparchive.close'>ziparchive.close</a>]: Invalid or unitialized Zip object

Comment: If you look at the file system, do you see the file.zip locally in the same path as the PHP file?: